# generate php classes in bash

Tags: php, bash

i have this script:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  if [[ -z "$1" ]] ; then
      echo "Class is required"
      exit 1;
  fi

  if [[ -z "$2" ]] ; then
      package="Default"
  else
      package=$2;
  fi

  echo "<?php
  /**
   * $1.class.php
   * 
   * Vcard class file.
   * @name        Project
   * @author      Author
   * @link        http://www.domain.com
   * @copyright   Copyright © 2011
   * @package     $package
   * @version     1.0
  */

  /**
   * The main $1 class
   * @package $package
  */
  class $1 {

      /**
       * Constructor setup.
       */
      public function __construct() {
      }

      /**
       * Destructor setup.
       */
      public function __destruct() {
      }
  }
  " > $1.class.php

  php -l $1.class.php
  echo "Done";
```

if i do:

./generate.sh my_class it creates everything with `my_class`. how can i modify this to: MyClass?

i need to use MyClass for the filename, and the class name etc... later in the code i use the argument (in this case my_class) for some other purposes.

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to ensure it's called MyClass you can add this somewhere after the validations:

```
fname=$( IFS='_'; for i in ${1,,}; do echo -n ${i^}; done )
```

And use `$fname.class.php`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is already set up for that. Just execute `./generate.sh MyClass`